# Post REST request from HTML button to Grapevine

Tags: html, rest, button, grapevine

I am trying to use Grapevine to let my .NET app interact with a webpage. I am currently in the process of learning.

I have the following REST route code:

```
    <RestRoute(HttpMethod:=HttpMethod.[GET], PathInfo:="/controller")>
    Public Function PlayerControl(ByVal context As IHttpContext) As IHttpContext
        Dim word = If(context.Request.QueryString("word"), "what?")
        Console.WriteLine(word)
        context.Response.SendResponse(word)
        Return context
    End Function
```

And on my webform I have:

```
 <form action="http://localhost:1234/controller" method="post">
         <input type="submit" name="?word=play" value="PLAY"/>
 </form>
```

The post reaches my application. I can see it in the console window. But it always reaches the default route:

```
   <RestRoute>
    Public Function HelloWorld(ByVal context As IHttpContext) As IHttpContext
        Console.WriteLine(context.ToString)
        context.Response.SendResponse("Message arrived at dfault window")
        Return context
    End Function
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your default route is being registered before the playercontrol route. As soon as the default route responds, the playercontrol route will not be invoked.

Either remove the default route, or (if you are using the default route scanner rather than manually registering routes) ensure that the default route method is located AFTER the playercontrol route in your class. If those routes are not in the same class, ensure that the class with the default route is